DB import issue on hostinger VPS
Facing timeout error when trying to import approx 2GB sql file in database in VPS account
Unable to import the admin_aohc dump:
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 129456: MySQL server has gone away
2024-06-07 21:59:03,749 [ERROR] 'mysql' finished with non-zero exit code: 1
Unable to flush stdout: Broken pipe

File adminer.sql is uploaded in root of website files directory, tried following methods still facing timeout issue:

Added file i root directory and used "Import Dump" tool from plesk panel
Tried to import compressed and uncompressed file directly to phpmyadmin
Tried importing via SSH

Tried above mentioned methods but facing same timeout error message
